# CheckComboBox set property doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, xceed

I'm using the XCeed CheckComboBox: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckComboBox&referringTitle=Home

In my ComboBox there are some types. All types are listed correctly in the combobox. My problem is, that if I uncheck an item, the set-property of `IsFiltered` isn't called:

Answer (score 0):

Most fields that end with `MemberPath` are looking for a string containing the property name.

In your case, you need

```
ValueMemberPath="IsFiltered"
```

instead of

```
ValueMemberPath="{Binding IsFiltered, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Right now its looking on your data object for a string property called `IsFiltered` that will tell it what property name to use for the `Value`, and since your `IsFiltered` is a bool, this doesn't work.

Comment: I think `ValueMemberPath` on this control is used to specify a sub-property of each selected item to include in the `SelectedValue`.  I don't think it reflects the selection state, i.e., whether the item was checked.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Ah you could be right. I got caught immediately by the incorrect usage of `ValueMemberPath` and did not consider that there may be other problems related to the design and usage of the `CheckedComboBox`. I haven't used XCeed's controls before, so am not sure how they work.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.CheckComboBox.html

And

https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.Selector~SelectedMemberPath.html

You'll need an ObservableCollection and a class holding the IsChecked and Item properties that fire the notifychanged event.

Below the working example: When you click the `Set A and C` button the items `A` and `C` will be checked as expected.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ViewModel viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new ViewModel();

            foreach (var item in new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D"})
            {
                viewModel.CheckComboBoxItems.Add(new CheckComboBoxItems { IsChecked = false, Item = item}); 
            }

            DataContext = viewModel;

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
            foreach (var checkBoxToSet in viewModel.CheckComboBoxItems)
            {
                if (checkBoxToSet.Item.Equals("A") || checkBoxToSet.Item.Equals("C"))
                {
                    checkBoxToSet.IsChecked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CheckComboBoxItems> CheckComboBoxItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CheckComboBoxItems>();
    }

    public class CheckComboBoxItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isChecked;
        private string _item;

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return _isChecked;
            }
            set
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }


        public string Item
        {
            get
            {
                return _item;
            }
            set
            {
                _item = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Item");
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <xctk:CheckComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CheckComboBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Item" SelectedMemberPath="IsChecked" Height="50" Width="150"/>
        <Button Content="Set A und C" Width="150" Height="50" Margin="20" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation, it doesn't look like there is a way to make the combo box bind the check box state to an item property.  Rather, the selected items are exposed via the `SelectedItems` property.  You can specify your own collection to hold the selected items with `SelectedItemsOverride`, so binding it to `IsFiltered` doesn't make sense.  What you'll probably have to do is bind `SelectedItemsOverride` to an `ObservableCollection<NapTypeItem>` and manually observe changes to the collection, and update the items' `IsFiltered` property when the selection changes.